# Can we say $X_n$ converge to 0 in probability?

Tags: probability, analysis

For a sequence of random variables $X_i$ for $i=1,\dots, n$, we have known the result
$$
X_n=O_p(n^{-1/3}).
$$

Can we say $X_n$ converge to 0 in probability?

---

It seems that $o_p$ means the convergence in probability. That means if $X_n=o_p(n)$, then,
$$
\frac{X_n}{n}\to0
$$
in probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then to show convergence in probability, we need to show that

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \Pr[|X_n| > \epsilon] = 0. $$

Another way of writing this is that for all $\delta > 0$ there exists an $N$ such that for all $n > N$ we have that

$$ \Pr[|X_n| > \epsilon] < \delta. $$

For any given $\delta$, since $X_n = O_p(n^{-1/3})$ we have that there exists an $M$ (dependent on $\delta$) and an $\hat{N}$ such that for all $n > \hat{N}$ we have that

$$ \Pr[|X_nn^{1/3}| > M ] = \Pr[|X_n| < Mn^{-1/3}] < \delta. $$

Now let $N = \max(\hat{N}, (M/\epsilon)^3)$. Then for all $n > N$ we have that $M n^{-1/3} \le \epsilon$. Thus, we get the needed statement.

Comment: So for any $X_n=O_p(a_n)$, we can say $X_n\to 0$ in probability?

Comment: $X_n=O_p(a_n)$ is stronger than $X_n=o_p(a_n)$?

Comment: If $a_n \to 0$.